# Images not getting saved in open cv write function

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to process images and try them to save them.
I am able to process it but image are not getting saved in folder

code - Taken from github

```
import cv2, glob, numpy

def scaleRadius(img,scale):
    x=img[int(img.shape[0]/2),:,:].sum(1)
    r=(x>x.mean()/10).sum()/2
    s=scale*1.0/r
    return cv2.resize(img,(0,0),fx=s,fy=s)

scale =512
for f in (glob.glob("pdr/*.jpeg")):

    a=cv2.imread(f)
    a=scaleRadius(a,scale)
    b=numpy.zeros(a.shape)
    cv2.circle(b,(int(a.shape[1]/2),int(a.shape[0]/2)),int(scale*0.9),(1,1,1),-1,8,0)
    aa=cv2.addWeighted(a,4,cv2.GaussianBlur(a,(0,0),scale/30),-4,128)*b+128*(1-b)
    cv2.imwrite(str(scale)+"_"+f,aa)
```

Code executes well but it output does not get saved

Comment: You ought to pass a proper path inside `cv2.imwrite()` in order to save the images. The code on github was posted to guide others using it. That does not mean you blindly copy it and expect it to work wonders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.imwrite()` doesn't create the directory for you, make sure you've created directory `512_pdr` before running the script.